# how can I check if a matrix is square using sympy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, sympy

To check if a matrix is square when the input is of the type `np.ndarray` i used

```
if len(V) != len(V[0]):
        raise ValueError('V is not a square matrix')
```

but when I want to use sympy, `len(V)`, for example for a 2x2 matrix, returns 4 instead of 2. I've tried using `v.shape` which returns (2,2), but I don't know how to implement a ValueError if the input matrix isn't square with this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape function should do what you want:

```
from sympy import shape

def isSquare(M):
   s = shape(M)
   return s[0] == s[1]
```

Also have a look at the [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html)

Comment: There is also `M.is_square`.